# Django - How to create a TableView out of many models that inherit same abstract class?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a TableView that displays all objects in my project that inherit from the same abstract class. I know I may have needed to make the original class not abstract, but the project is already running and I'd rather not change the models now.

The abstract class is this:

```
class WarehouseBase(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='Región')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nombre', unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And the classes that inherit from it are:

```
class SaleWarehouse(WarehouseBase):
    TYPES = (
        (0, 'Autotanque'),
        (1, 'Estación de carburación')
    )
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Tipo')
    # price = models.ForeignKey(SpecificPrice, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='warehouse')
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)

    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Precio', validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(1000.0)], null=True, blank=True)
    price_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha de precio', null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(str(self.pk), self.name)


class GeneralWarehouse(WarehouseBase):
    @property
    def total_capacity(self):
        capacity = 0.0
        for tank in self.tanks:
            capacity += tank.max_capacity
        return capacity

    def __str__(self):
        return "Almacén general '{}'".format(self.name)
```

The new requirement for a view that enlists all warehouses was just added, but when the project was made this was not needed. I've been searching and I've found ways to change the database models so that I can make a queryset of WarehouseBase objects, but it would require many changes in the database that would be very dangerous now that several functionalities depend on those models.

Is there a way to just make the TableView display all SaleWarehouse and GeneralWarehouse objects, without changing the models?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list of objects or dictionary and add objects from both models , SaleWarehouse and GeneralWarehouse. This way you can combine data from both models in a single list without any changes to the database.